# Prevent blur effect on disabled UISlider

Tags: ios, uislider, blur

In iOS7, if I set `enabled = NO` in a `UISlider`, it is automatically blurred.

[image: enabled and disabled (blurred) slider]

Is there a way to prevent this blurring?

I could set `userInteraction = NO` on the view to ignore touches, but ideally, i'd like to be able to set the enabled state of the slider so that I could still customize the slider for the `UIControlStateDisabled` state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclass UISlider and override the setEnabled: method without calling [super setEnabled:enabled]. You'll need to synthesize an ivar for the enabled property and manually set the ivar to the correct state:

```
@implementation STKSlider
@synthesize enabled = _enabled;

- (void)setEnabled:(BOOL)enabled
{
    _enabled = enabled;

    // Add custom state logic here
}
```

Comment: Nice. Yes, the default for `enabled` is now `NO`. The only other disadvantage is that `-[UISlider setThumbImage:image forState:UIControlStateDisabled]` doesn't work, and needs to be set manually in the `setEnabled` method.